# Understanding Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to understand Kusto (Log Analytics Query Language in Azure).

According to the documentation;

To retrieve , `project name` and `resultsCode` from the `dependencies` table, I need to enter the following:

```
dependencies 
| project name, resultCode
```

The machines I have subscribed to do not have this table.

I am using the `heartbeat` table and trying to retrieve computer and category like so:

```
Heartbeat 
| Category, Computer , IsGatewayInstalled
```

I however get the following error:

Query could not be parsed at 'Category' on line [2,2]

> Token: Category Line: 2 Position: 2

This seems trivial and will appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error you're getting is due to the fact there's no valid operator after the pipe (`|`), you should use the `project` operator before specifying the column names you want to retrieve

Comment: Thanks!! you wouldnt know why my syslog table is empty? do i need to install the agent on each VM? I had assumed just connected it in the portal would allow me to aggregate these logs

Comment: you may want to post a different question about that (no need for the `kusto` tag there)